# Переведите пожалуйста на питон

Tags: python, информатика

```pascal
var R:real;
function sfera(r:real):real;
begin
sfera:=4*PI*r*r;
end;
berin
Readln(R);
writeln(sfera(R));
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так. Шаги максимально приближены к оригиналу:

```py
r = "" # Эта строка по сути ненужна
def sfera(r):
    sfera=float(4)*3.14*float(r)*float(r)
    return sfera

r = input("Введите число:")
print(sfera(r))
```

Comment: на данном сайте не принято отвечать на вопросы-переводы

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
r = input("Введите радиус: ")
def sfera(r):
   sfera = float(4) * math.pi * float(r) * float(r) 
   print(sfera)
    
sfera(r)
```